# Toggling a horizontal axis on a key_event in Python with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot some data and when I click on a certain key I want horizontal axis to appear, as boundaries.

This works fine, but I would also like to then press the button a second time and remove the boundary lines. Is this possible from an event callback with Matplotlib?

What I have so far:

```
def on_key(event):
    
    if event.key == 'b':   

        plot.axhline(y = boundary, color = 'green', linestyle = '-')
 
    plot.draw()
```

Ive tried setting a boolean variable for the axhline visibility to toggle on each entry to the callback but unfortunately doesnt seem to work.

Ive also tried setting the color to white but then this affects the underlying data and is still quite noticable in the plot.

Is there a way to simply remove this axhline, even with a serperate button press for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this documentation page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/event_handling/keypress_demo.html), we can create the `axhline` and toggle its visibility on every key press.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def on_press(event):
    visible = line.get_visible()
    line.set_visible(not visible)
    fig.canvas.draw()


rng = np.random.default_rng(42)

N = 10
x = np.linspace(0, 5, N)
y = rng.random(N)
y_mean = np.mean(y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", on_press)

ax.plot(x, y, ".")
line = ax.axhline(y_mean, color="g")
line.set_visible(False)
fig.show()
```

Note: The `on_press` function is taking the `line` variable from the global scope. That isn't the best practice. if you want to explicitly pass the line, we can use `functools.partial` to create a version of the event that has that variable passed automatically.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from functools import partial


def on_press_with_line(event, line):
    visible = line.get_visible()
    line.set_visible(not visible)
    fig.canvas.draw()


rng = np.random.default_rng(42)

N = 10
x = np.linspace(0, 5, N)
y = rng.random(N)
y_mean = np.mean(y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y, ".")
line = ax.axhline(y_mean, color="g")
line.set_visible(False)
on_press = partial(on_press_with_line, line=line)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", on_press)
fig.show()
```

Or we can use a `lambda` function.

```py
fig.canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", lambda event: on_press_with_line(event, line))
```